# How to combine Scoups and WoS data for biblioshiny in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, bibtex, scopus

I am tring to conduct a basic bibliometrix analysis using biblioshiny. However, since I have both Scopus and WoS databases, I am finding it difficult to combine them. So far, I have been able to import both the data using codes in R, and I have also already combined them. But I can't figure out how to use this combined data as input into the biblioshiny() app.

```
#Importing WoS and Scopus data individually
m1 = convert2df("WOS.txt", "wos", "plaintext")
m2 = convert2df("scopus.csv", "scopus", "csv")

#Merging them
M = mergeDbSources(m1, m2, remove.duplicated = TRUE)

#Creating the results
results = biblioAnalysis(M, sep = ";")
```

I just need to know how to export the results in a relevant format for data input in biblioshiny. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the WOS data files (in txt format) into a zip file and upload that zip file into biblioshiny. That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(results, file="mergedfile.xlsx")
```

it will save results with a name of mergedfile